# Как сохранить и загрузить данные Android

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-shared-preferences

Доброго времени суток. Есть класс Time с 2-мя полями типа String, на основе этого класса создан ArrayList, Custom Adapter который наследует BaseAdapter, ListView  в котором отображается 2 поля из класса.
   Как можно сохранять и при новом запуске приложения загружать эти два поля используя SharedPreference, или что-то другое лучше подойдет данной ситуации? 
До этого я пользовался такой реализацией, но она для одной строки. К тому же Custom Adapter не поддерживает метод add(). Впервые работаю с Custom Adapter.

```
 private void loadPresetList(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences){
    for (int i = 0;; ++i){
        final String data = sharedPreferences.getString(String.valueOf(i), "");
        if(!data.equals("")){
            eventAdapter.add(data);
        }else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
private void savePresetList(){
    editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < eventAdapter.getCount(); ++i){
        editor.putString(String.valueOf(i), adapter.getItem(i));
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: SQLite - универсальное решение для общего случая сохранения данных. Что значит *"впервые работаю с `CustomAdapter`, он не поддерживает `add()`"*? - это класс, который вы **пишите сами**, как он может что то не поддерживать, если его написали ВЫ

Comment: Да, не совсем точно выразился, BaseAdapter не имеет метода add().